# Incorrect pgfplot dateplot - shifted by a day

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

Using `dateplot` the data is horizontally shifted by a day I and cannot see the reason why. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,value
2015-01-01, 3.2
2015-01-04, 6.5
2015-01-10, 6.8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\day-\month-\year},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel={Date (day-month-year)},
    ylabel={Value},
]
\addplot table [x=date, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The dates are on 1,4 and 10th of January, but the plot shows differently:
[image]

Comment: Strangely, if I change the last date "2015-01-10" into "2015-01-08"; the plot is correct.

Comment: Unrelated comment: Don't write `$day-month-year$`, those aren't supposed to be minus signs. If you want italics, use `\textit{day-month-year}`.

Comment: Thnks @TorbjørnT. I changed it in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why it happens, but a quick fix is to add `date ZERO=2015-01-01`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date,value
2015-01-01, 3.2
2015-01-04, 6.5
2015-01-10, 6.8
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\day-\month-\year},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    date ZERO=2015-01-01,
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel={Date (day-month-year)},
    ylabel={Value},
]
\addplot table [x=date, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks this works indeed, still curious WHY the plot doesn't work in the first place. It doesn't make `pgfplot` very reliable in my opinion

Comment: @API (More or less) All software has bugs, possibly this is one. Christian Feuersänger may have seen this already, but I'll add a bug report at SourceForge anyway.

Comment: @API See https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/96/

Comment: Now using `date ZERO=2015-01-01` this bug in some conditions still occurs!

Comment: @API Well, there's not really much point in complaining here, I'm not a dev for `pgfplots`, and it's unlikely that Christian Feuersänger sees your comment. Is 2015-01-01 the first coordinate in your data? If not, try setting `date ZERO` to that date.  Other than that, post a comment to the bug report (see link above), with another MWE.